# Script to do incremental backups with rsync

Tags: linux, bash

Could someone help me with a bash script in linux to make backups. would have to do a full backup every week and every day an incremental.

Comment: sorry, this isn't a code completion service. Show us what you have tried so far. Similar questions get asked here on S.O on a regular basis. Good luck.

Comment: `rsync` is designed to do incremental backups---it only transfers the information that has been changed.  Something like this should work: `rsync -avz /data/ /mnt/backup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to use or borrow ideas from Backup.rsync [here](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/Backup.remote.html).

I actually used to do rsync backups via Backup.rsync, but I've since switched to my [backshift](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/backshift/) program because it deduplicates better (no more O(length^2) storage requirement for large, slow-growing files), and compresses the chunks with xz.  If you look it over, you'll likely see that it's inspired by rsync --link-dest.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org) for over four years to keep a rotation of 7 daily, 4 weekly, and 12 monthly snapshots of my Slackware Box.  Because it intelligently uses hardlinks, all 23 of these snapshots only take about 30% more space than the entire size of my filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend `rdiff-backup`, available on popular distros, and is [very capable](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/features.html).

It has a Windows build as well!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the --link-dest switch of rsync to create incrementals.
Simply do one full rsync and do a incremental with --link-dest=<path_to_full>.

Comment: can you clarify a bit more on how this works?